# How to send the home page after hiting a specific route [Express/Nodejs]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to redirect to the home page after a user hit this route: `/ref=123` but I want to keep that `baseUrl`, this is what I have so far:

I am requiring in my `server.js` file this: `const referred = require('./routes/referred')`.

```
app.use('/ref=:id', (req, res, next) => {
    res.locals = req.params.id
}, referred)
```

So, when a user hits the above route I am doing some validations in my `referred.js` file. Actually I need to send some kind of response telling whether that provided `id` exist or not but showing anyways the home page which is a simple login/resgistration form.

```
referred.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    //doing validations with res.locals
    next() //<- calling the next middleware
})
```

after calling `next()` I put that middleware just below to redirect to the home page.

not sure if this is possible: `app.use(express.static(_dirname + '/dist'))` it seems like is not because I'm getting a `404` .

I know I could use the `req.redirect()` function but that will actually made a new request to the server and refresh the page erasing the `baseUrl` that I want to keep up there.

Comment: Not sure what exactly this is asking.  Are you asking how to redirect or how to save information across requests or something entirely different?

Comment: I'm asking how to redirect to the home page when a user hits the route: `/ref=:id` but at the same time maintain that base url on the search bar, for example, keeping this: `/ref=123` and also the possibility of sending a response whether that `id` exists or not

Answer (score 0):

How do you render/send your pages?

You could use `res.sendFile('path/to/page.html')` to send back any html file while keeping the request URL.

If you want to display a dynamic message on the home page, you should use a viewing engine like `ejs`. If you are already using an engine, you can do something like

`res.render('path/to/page', { status: 'This id does not exist!'})`

Comment: It is a single page application I only have one page, and I am using Vue in the front end, the way I serve that single page is doing: `app.use(express.static(_dirname + '/dist'))`. I try to use `sendFile()` but It doesn't send any of my assets like css/js files only sends the `html`. I really don't want to use `ejs` because is too much weight for a single page.

Comment: Are your css/js paths relative? E.g. the browser tries to load /ref:=id/script.js instead of /script.js. Try to look up the requests the browser makes via developer console

Comment: yes my assets are relative to my `/dist` folder and that is exactly what it happends, I am able to send the `index.html` file but when it comes to the assets what I get is a `404` for thoses files: `css/js`. I don't understand, hook up the request to the browser?

Comment: Can you post your script/link lines from the html header? The ones that look like `<link href="...">` and `<script src="...">` I'm interested in how href/src look, your problem might be there

Comment: I put my CSS at the top between the head tags and my script at the bottom just before the closing body tag. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">` & `<script src="./bundle.js"></script>`

Comment: Try `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">` and <script src="/bundle.js">. This makes both paths absolute (not relative to the current base url)